# sed replace in conf 2 different patterns

Tags: bash, shell

i want to replace 2 entrys in conf file with sed

```
# Set Server
/bin/sed -i 's/server: 127.0.0.1/server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/' /etc/cobbler/settings

# Set next Server
/bin/sed -i 's/next_server: 127.0.0.1/next_server: 192.168.122.1/' /etc/cobbler/settings
```

for some reason it changes the the primary entry on both, why ? i use 2 different patterns to check for  "server" & "next_server"

also i would like to know how i could change a quoted string pattern

```
#change default password    
/bin/sed -i 's/default_password_crypted: "$1$mF86/UHC$WvcIcX2t6crBz2onWxyac."/default_password_crypted: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/' /etc/cobbler/settings
```

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `^` to the beginning of your regexp to require the line starting with exactly that string.

```
# Set Server
/bin/sed -i 's/^server: 127.0.0.1/server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/' /etc/cobbler/settings

# Set next Server
/bin/sed -i 's/^next_server: 127.0.0.1/next_server: 192.168.122.1/' /etc/cobbler/settings
```

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because your first matching regex is:

```
server: 127.0.0.1
```

And 2nd one is:

```
next_server: 127.0.0.1
```

As you can see first regex will match both the patterns since `server: 127.0.0.1` is found for both cases.

**Fix:** To avoid unwanted matching **you need to use word boundaries** like this:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\b\(server: \)127.0.0.1/\1xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/' /etc/cobbler/settings
```

**Note:** On OSX you need to use this weird syntax for word boundaries:

```
sed -i.bak 's/[[:<:]]\(server: \)127.0.0.1/\1xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/' /etc/cobbler/settings
```

Answer (score 1):

If your line `server: 127.0.0.1` has no extra space or other string in the line,
you should add `^` and `$`.

```
/bin/sed -i 's/^server: 127.0.0.1$/server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/' /etc/cobbler/settings
```

And your second question, you need to escape `$`.

```
/bin/sed -i 's;default_password_crypted: "\$1\$mF86/UHC\$WvcIcX2t6crBz2onWxyac.";default_password_crypted: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";' /etc/cobbler/settings
```

Comment: trying your solution on changing password hash gives me error:    

`sed: -e expression #1, char 69: unknown option to `s'`